# Warum wird „anerkennen“ teils als untrennbar betrachtet?

Tags: prefix, separable-verb

Das Verb *anerkennen* wird auch in Zeitungen in beiden Varianten gebraucht – trennbar und nicht trennbar. Hier zwei fiktive Beispiele:

> Ich anerkenne seine Leistung.
>
> Ich erkenne seine Leistung an.

Das Verb setzt sich aus dem sonst immer separierbaren Präfix *an* und dem bereits präfigierten Verb *erkennen* zusammen.
Das *an* ist ganz klar betont und betonte Vorsilben werden abgetrennt.

- Gibt es irgendeinen nachvollziehbaren Grund, es als nicht trennbar zu betrachten?
- Seit wann gibt es beide Lesarten?
- Wo kommt das her?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Duden online gibt [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anerkennen) die Lösung unter der Rubrik Grammatik:

> unregelmäßiges Verb; erkennt an/(besonders schweizerisch:) anerkennt, erkannte an/(besonders schweizerisch:) anerkannte, hat anerkannt

Die zusammengesetzte Form ist demnach also die schweizerische Variante. Es gibt sie schon [sehr lange](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_+ich+anerkenne&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C_START_%20ich%20anerkenne%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B_START_%20Ich%20anerkenne%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B_START_%20ich%20anerkenne%3B%2Cc0). In Analogie zu *auferstehen* ist sie wahrscheinlich als eine alte Form [untrennbarer Verben](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4fix#Trennbare_und_untrennbare_Verben) anzusehen, die sich im südlichen Raum gehalten hat.

Comment: weißt du zufällig, ob das in der Schweiz generell so ist? Oder zumindest tendenziell?.. Und ich bin verwirrt über die Gruppierung in deinem Zitat... was bezieht sich auf was?

Comment: @Emanuel: weiß ich nicht, ich bin nicht aus dieser Ecke. Im Zitat hast du die 2 Formen für Präsens (als zweites die schweizerische Version), dann 3 Formen für Präteritum (als zweites wieder schweizerisch), alle 5 für die 3. Person Einzahl

Comment: Der Duden scheint sich da aber auf ein Schweizer-Standard-Hochdeutsch zu beziehen denn ich habe ungefähr 10 Schweizer aus allen Teilen der deutschen Schweiz (außer Zürich) um ihre Meinung gefragt und keiner wollte etwas von 'ich anerkannte' im Imperfekt wissen. Höchstens mit Naserümpfen tolerieren...

Comment: @mramosch Frag doch die zehn Schweizer bitte noch, ob »ich anerkenne (seine Leistung)« für sie in Ordnung ist. Für mich käme nur »ich erkenne seine Leistung an« in Frage ;)

Comment: @Jan: Beim Schweizer gibt es eine eindeutige Grenze zwischen Hochsprache und Dialekt. In der Hochsprache sagt er eindeutig ***'Ich anerkannte'*** -> *'Ich erkannte ... an'* klingt für meine Probanden alle 'total falsch'! Auch wenn es in das Perfekt geht bleibt natürlich *'Ich habe ... anerkannt'*. Wenn es aber ins Schwizer-Dütsch geht, gibt es so gut wie keinen Imperfekt!!! Deshalb stellt sich die Frage von oben natürlich erst gar nicht!

Comment: @Jan: Die Hochsprache ist für den Schweizer eine Bürde in der er sich beim Übersetzen aus dem Dialekt ziemlich oft mit grammatikalischen Stolpersteinen verheddert. Wenn das Gespräch schon in der Hochsprache stattfindet, gibt es kein Problem - nur wenn man ihn um eine Übersetzung des eben Gesagten fragt wird es ziemlich oft holprig...

Comment: @mramosch Lies nochmal genauer, i hab absichtlich nach dem Präsens gefragt ;)

Comment: @Jan: Auch im Präsens gilt '***Ich anerkenne seine Leistung***'... - Es geht hier nicht so sehr um die Zeit selber, sondern ob es sich um eine einfache oder zusammengesetzte Zeitform handelt. Präsens wird gleich wie Imperfekt benutzt -> ich anerkenne/anerkannte/habe anerkannt/hatte anerkannt. '***Anerkannt***' wird einfach nur ungetrennt als 'korrekt' empfunden - sei es eine einfache oder zusammengesetzte Zeitform... - Sorry, für das Missverständnis ;-)

Comment: @Jan: Und das gilt bei '***anerkennen***' sowohl für die Schweizer Hochsprache als auch den Dialekt...